# Do the model results of multiple linear regressions remain the same if I take the log of dependent variable?

Tags: regression

I have results of 2 multiple linear regression models, one with log of dependent variable and other with the original variable. I notice the change in significance and goodness of fit. Why is that?

### Wit y:

```
Call:
lm(formula = (Duration_CS.x.x) ~ gap.s_lcf + acc_pedal_pos_EF + 
    expr_lt1 + speed.kph.ED_lcf, data = ds_c_trucks)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.3740 -1.1398 -0.1173  1.2491  7.8812 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      12.586614   1.131682  11.122   <2e-16 ***
gap.s_lcf         0.141980   0.081959   1.732   0.0856 .  
acc_pedal_pos_EF -1.625288   0.622018  -2.613   0.0100 *  
expr_lt11        -1.550120   0.702220  -2.207   0.0290 *  
speed.kph.ED_lcf -0.017690   0.009388  -1.884   0.0617 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.125 on 131 degrees of freedom
  (3 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1478,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1217 
F-statistic: 5.678 on 4 and 131 DF,  p-value: 0.0003023
```

### With log(y)

```
Call:
lm(formula = log(Duration_CS.x.x) ~ gap.s_lcf + acc_pedal_pos_EF + 
    expr_lt1 + speed.kph.ED_lcf, data = ds_c_trucks)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.84821 -0.09087  0.00549  0.13228  0.60341 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       2.5797819  0.1161440  22.212   <2e-16 ***
gap.s_lcf         0.0146764  0.0084115   1.745   0.0834 .  
acc_pedal_pos_EF -0.2046169  0.0638375  -3.205   0.0017 ** 
expr_lt11        -0.1564983  0.0720685  -2.172   0.0317 *  
speed.kph.ED_lcf -0.0020781  0.0009635  -2.157   0.0328 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.218 on 131 degrees of freedom
  (3 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1761,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.151 
F-statistic: 7.002 on 4 and 131 DF,  p-value: 3.86e-05
```

Comment: You are transforming the variable. After that, do you expect no change in results?

Comment: The response variable is measured on a completely different scale and the fit on the original scale is entirely different. Why would anything be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to imagine why this would be different, looking at one of the most simple parameters available in statistics: the mean.

Take a random set of numbers, e.g.:

2  5  9 14 25 17 26 68  3 67 35 65.
 The mean of this set of numbers is **28**. Now log transform this set: 
0.6931472 1.6094379 2.1972246 2.6390573 3.2188758 2.8332133 3.2580965 4.2195077 1.0986123 4.2046926 3.5553481 4.1743873
The mean of this is 2.808467, which is **16.58447** when you exponentiate it!

Knowing this, it seems to me it's not hard to see that any other kind of statistics would suffer a similar fate. The question you should consider is: Why did you choose to try a model with the log-transformed dependent variable? There is always a reason to consider transforming your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize now that there is no change in the interpretation of results (sign of coefficients) after the transformation.